# Powershell: SQL Server Management Studio Script Generator

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, ssms

I use the Script Generator which is integrated in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to generate an import script for a whole database.

[image]
[image]

I have to do some replacements in the script which I do with Powershell. Now I want to automate the generation. Is there a way to execute exactly this Script Generator Tool (and setting some options as on the screenshot - in my case 'Data only')? Or (if this isn't possible) can I open this tool window automatically from a ps script so I don't have to open the Management Studio, selecting the DB, ...?

I found some scripts which 'manually' build the script file in Powershell but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56616/sql-server-2012-generate-scripts-from-command-line

Comment: You can create a SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) project http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/sql-server-management-objects-create-database-table-scripts.aspx as shown in referred SQL tutorial for scripting database objects into a text file.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your hints and ideas! I want to try it via SMO but got a problem with it. I think it's a good idea to post a new question for this and I will post the link here.

Answer (score 7):

This question's been here awhile and you've probably found your answer by now, but for those looking for a simple way to do this, the current versions of SQL server Powershell modules have native commands and methods that support this functionality from SMO.

You can use **Get-SqlDatabase** and methods such as **.Script()** and **.EnumScript().**

For example, this will generate CREATE scripts for user defined functions and save it to file:

```
$Database = Get-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $YourSqlServer -Name $YourDatabaseName

$MyFuncs = $Database.UserDefinedFunctions | Where Schema -eq "dbo"
$MyFuncs.Script() | Out-File -FilePath ".\SqlScripts\MyFunctions.sql"
```

If you want to **script data** and elements like indexes, keys, triggers, etc. you will have to specify the scripting options, like this:

```
$scriptOptions = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions

$scriptOptions.NoCollation = $True
$scriptOptions.Indexes = $True
$scriptOptions.Triggers = $True
$scriptOptions.DriAll = $True
$scriptOptions.ScriptData = $True

$Database.Tables.EnumScript($scriptOptions) | Out-File -FilePath ".\AllMyTables.sql"
```

Note that the Script() method doesn't support scripting data. Use EnumScript() for tables.

If you want to script data only, as asked, you can try `$scriptOptions.ScriptData = $True` and `$scriptOptions.ScriptSchema = $False`.