# Why does .Script and .EnumScript not accept ScriptingOptions objects as arguments?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scripting, smo

**Background**
I'm working on a tech debt project where I'm revising my team's build processes.  In this, I'm working on being able to deploy database changes from a local database to our Dev database using scripts that are generated by our build process.

When researching an alternative to our current process, I came across [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633990/powershell-sql-server-management-studio-script-generator), which has an answer that includes some Powershell script fragments that use SQL Studio's `Get-SqlDatabase` cmdlet to get a handle on the set of tables, and call `.Script(ScriptingOptions)` to generate a SQL script file.

**Problem**
Whenever I try to run the following script...

```
$Database = Get-SqlDatabase -Name "MyRadDatabase" -ServerInstance "(local)\MyLocalDb"
$Options = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions
# For sanity check, I'm not setting any options!
$Database.Tables.Script($Options)
```

...I get the following error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Script" and the argument count: "1".
At line:4 char:1
+ $Database.Tables.Script($Options)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

In addition, I did the following things before asking this question:

- Included a set of valid options
- Called `EnumScript` instead of `Script`
- Attempted to create a `Scripter` object, which could have `.Script` called with options

...Which, of course, is *wrong* according to the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.script?view=sql-smo-160#microsoft-sqlserver-management-smo-database-script)...

...Though, that documentation is also pretty woefully *wrong* as well.  For instance, while it is possible to call `$Database.Tables.Script()` - which, `TableCollection` doesn't have a noted `Script` or `EnumScript` function in the documentation - all instances of the `Script` and `EnumScript` methods tends to include an overload that accepts a `ScriptingOptions` method as an argument so that the programmer has better control over the script that the SQL Server CLI generates.

**Question**
In what way can I control how the SMO Scripting functionality generates SQL scripts?

Comment: Do you have the correct version of the SMO so you can call these methods?

Comment: That is a good question.  Are there any resources that I could use to know how to check?  Also, what version of SMO should have these methods?

Comment: I don't see `Script` as an available method for a [TableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.tablecollection?view=sql-smo-160) (which is what you're calling when you're doing `$Database.Tables.Script($Options)`)

Comment: I mentioned that in my question.  If you open a Powershell instance, set a connection string, then call `$Database.Tables.Script()`, you will get SQL output in your window.  In this case, the Microsoft documentation is wrong, which has been a major obstacle in figuring out how to get SQL Server to generate a DB script.

Comment: If you run ```$Database.Tables.Script```(no brackets or parameters, just the bare method name) it will return all of the implemented overloads of the ```Script``` method - if you post the output from that it might give some useful info…

Comment: Did you read the link?  It says "Note that the Script() method doesn't support scripting data. Use EnumScript() for tables"

Comment: It doesn't answer the question you asked, but if you're just trying to get a script for all of your tables, you could do `$Database.Tables | % {$_.Script($Options)}`.